# Is it ok for a canonical link to point to itself?

Tags: canonical-url

I've got the canonical:

```
<link href="http://www.Site.com/Blog/how-to-know-when-this" rel="canonical" />
```

Is it ok if this is on the page it is pointing to?

Also I'm putting it on all these pages:

```
http://www.Site.com/Blog/how-to-know-when-this
http://www.Site.com/Blog/how-to-know-when-this/
http://www.Site.com/Blog.aspx?ID=1
http://www.Site.com/Blog/how-to-know-when-this/?q=
```

Is this correct useage?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use rel='canonical' properly](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/848/how-to-use-rel-canonical-properly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's perfectly fine to do. It's just redundant and doesn't do any harm.

Comment: I do it all the time because it makes programming easier when you have multiple pages with the same code and it helps me remember which page is the canonical page when I look back much later.

Comment: @RandomBen yeah that's why I've done it, it's just easier than writing an exclusion rule as well

Comment: I wouldn't call it redundant at all. This is exactly the point of a canonical tag - to tell search engines the preferred URL of a page. If the current URL is the preferred URL then you need to specify that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Update to this question:
Google says it is OK to point the canonical tag to itself. Bing recommends against it.

Comment: Can you link to the sources you used that explains why Bing recommends against it?

Comment: [This post](http://www.northsideseo.com/google-vs-bing-canonical-tag/) summarizes it all!