# URL without trailing slash makes Apache look in non-SSL DocumentRoot

Tags: apache, redirects, https

I have configured a virtual host in Apache for serving content over SSL/TLS. Since I also want to allow other sites on my domain to use regular http, I have two document roots, one at `/home/www/html` and one at `/home/www/html-ssl`. I force SSL on my site with the following directives in a file in `/etc/httpd/conf.d`:

```
<Directory /home/www/html-ssl/foo>
    SSLOptions +StrictRequire
    SSLRequireSSL
    SSLRequire ( %{HTTP_HOST} eq "mydomain.com" )
    ErrorDocument 403 https://mydomain.com/foo
</Directory>
```

This redirects any requests for `http://mydomain.com/foo/` to `https://mydomain.com/foo/`. However, when I try to access `http://mydomain.com/foo` without the trailing slash, Apache searches for `foo` in `/home/www/html` instead of in `/home/www/html-ssl`, causing a 404. Is there a way to tell Apache that `http://mydomain.com/foo` should really look for the directory `foo` in `/home/www/html-ssl`, and then redirect to the https site? I thought that since DirectorySlash is on, Apache would be able to figure out that `foo` is a directory, at which point it would see my `<Directory>` section above and work its magic.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative fix would be to enforce the trailing slash on the end of your URLS - this would have the benefit of preventing duplicates if your not using [Rel Canonical](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/848/how-to-use-rel-canonical-properly/849#849).

> **[SOURCE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47270/what-are-the-most-commonly-used-and-basic-apache-htaccess-redirects)**
>
> This will redirect all requests without a tailing / to the URL with
>   the slash on the end. (note within the 2nd part of the bracket is
>   those file extensions to ignore.. Since it wouldn't make sense to
>   enforce / on a picture URL.
>
> `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.(php|html?|jpg|gif)$`
>
> `RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2/ [L,R=301]`

Comment: Thanks bybe, this looks like it will come in handy even if I don't use it for this particular issue.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. I'm not sure if this is the *best* solution, but I figured out how to do this using a combination of mod_rewrite and the `<Directory>` section I already had. Basically, any requests coming in on ports other than 443 were going to my non-SSL virtual host (duh), so Apache was mapping the URLs to files in the non-SSL document root (`/home/www/html`). If I rewrite all non-https requests for `foo` to https using mod_rewrite, the new requests will use port 443 and Apache can resolve to the correct directory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/foo [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com?
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

<Directory /home/www/html-ssl/foo>
    SSLOptions +StrictRequire
    SSLRequireSSL
    SSLRequire ( %{HTTP_HOST} eq "mydomain.com" )
    ErrorDocument 403 https://mydomain.com/foo
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

And yet another, simpler solution. Instead of using mod_rewrite, just create an alias mapping `/foo` to the correct directory:

```
Alias /foo /home/www/html-ssl/foo
<Directory /home/www/html-ssl/foo>
    SSLOptions +StrictRequire
    SSLRequireSSL
    SSLRequire ( %{HTTP_HOST} eq "mydomain.com" )
    ErrorDocument 403 https://mydomain.com/foo
</Directory>
```