# Confusion for specifying rel="canonical" for pages

Tags: seo, canonical-url

I read [this link](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139394?hl=en) & [even this also](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/848/how-to-use-rel-canonical-properly), but I am still confused. That's why I plan to ask here, Please confirm me with your answer.

My doubt is I have two pages: `GridViewPage.php` & `ListViewPage.php` having same content. So according to this in which page I have insert this code `<link rel="canonical" href="which url I should put here"/>`.

And for opening `GridViewPage.php` page URL looks like: `http://example.com/article/show/abdominal-exercises/abdominal-crunch/79/87/list/`.

& for opening `GridViewPage.php` page my URL looks like: `http://example.com/article/show/abdominal-exercises/abdominal-crunch/79/87/grid/`.

Note: 79/87 are the dynamic database table id's.

Comment: Please do not ask a question again after it has been closed. Edit the original question which can then be reopened if appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `a.com/listview.php` to be indexed instead `gridview.php`, you will add the following to `gridview.php`:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.a.com/listview.php" />
```

And the opposite for the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

Something to note is that the url in the canonical tag should match your preferred version of your site, either www or non-www. So if your site is `http://example.com` then the canonical tag would be

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/article/show/abdominal-exercises/abdominal-crunch/79/87/grid/" />
```

Comment: one doubt, if instead of `..../grid/` in the cononical url if i specified ``..../grid`   then is this makes diffrence?

Comment: You should try and ensure the url in the canonical tag is exactly the same as the target url.

Comment: @dan Here is my real-time implementation example: URL of my first page  is like this `http://mysite.com/article/show/abdominal-exercises/ball-pass/108/111/list`  and on my second similar content page,i specified as `<link rel="canonical" href="http://mysite.com/article/show/abdominal-exercises/ball-pass/108/111/list"/>` in the header.                                               What you say dan,is this correct or i have doing mistake?