# How to enforce WWW without htaccess

Tags: seo, redirects

URL canonization is an important aspect in SEO, now I have a website hosted on Yahoo my small business which doesn't allow for .htaccess to be uploaded, now in such a case how do I keep my domain consistent.

**[HERE](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/www-no-www/)** is a Chris coyer script i came across, it shows how to make the URL, consistent using the .htaccess file. but now obviously I can't use the .htaccess file , so how to I make my URL consistent when my host doesn't allow me to upload a .htaccess file?

Comment: Simple fix would be to use [canonical](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/848/how-to-use-rel-canonical-properly), this would inform Google the master pages, this would do the trick without redirecting pages, however this doesn't solve the issue of you using a host that doesn't support things it should.

Comment: What scripting languages can you use?

Comment: @w3d , PHP is my prefered scripting language !

Comment: @bybe , i get the following url in the browser `www.example.co.in` so for t he canonical link sould i use `<link rel="canonical" href="www.ferroli.co.in" />` ? sorry first time doing this :P

Answer (score 4):

You could make a very simple test to see if there is `www` in the URL, and if it hasn't, go to the `www` version via a [301 permanently moved](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) header:

```
if( substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],0,4)!='www.'){
    header('Location: http://www.'$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], true, 301);
}
```

Don't forget to set your canonical tags to `www` so bots know your preferred URL.

Comment: There's a similar answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7228702/3913970
Note that Martijn's answer won't work as HOST_NAME isn't defined in the $_SERVER array and there's a concatenation operator missing.

Comment: The URL used in the `Location` header should be absolute, starting with a scheme ie. `http://www...`.

Comment: A canonical tag isn't really necessary if the Location header is used because you're doing a redirect and only the target page will return the document. Also, if you use the location header, you should also include this HTTP header: `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently`.

Comment: The canonical should be one of the things `you just do`. It saves you work in the long run (in my experience). The header has a 301 value, if you scroll to the right a bit you can see it :)